# Why is my house cat trying to jump out my upper sash windows?

Tags: cats, behavior

The only time she has tried to jump in the 18 weeks of her being a happy though clingy pussy cat (mummy's girl) is when she was in heat and I had a horrid guest who stank of dog (a scent she is unaccustomed to anyway being a house cat). Luna is also a very nervous cat unless just with me (then she's the opposite). Other than that, those little upper windows have always been open, even at night, and she's been FINE, even when in heat which I know is distressing for her (getting her "done" next month).

My step dad has recently started visiting as my carer and since this started she has stopped coming to bed with me. More to the point, this is the second time, two days in a row, that I have found her halfway out the little sash windows. She normally loves being on the windowsill but my instinct told me to peek behind the curtain and my instinct told me right. She jumped down unaware of her near death. Luna isn't a silly cat. She is smart. I did start shutting the windows but wanted to give her the benefit of the doubt. Looks like I can't.

Any ideas as to why she doesn't seem herself?
She's very used to it just being us apart from support workers occasionally popping in so maybe my step dad being here for hours on end several times a week so suddenly as well as her being in heat has upset her more than I anticipated?

Comment: why have you not got her spayed,a spayed queen is less likely to have the need for getting out and about,other things you might want to consider is a spayed cat have a greatly reduced risk of cancer.

Comment: Also definitely consider putting something in front of your windows. Preventing your cat from going there but still trying to maintain air circulation

Answer (score 3):

It's normal for an unspayed cat at her age to have the urge to roam.  Cats are also curious, and she could have seen something outside that interested her.

Although it's quite possible that having guests and having visitors in the house more could be upsetting her, you can help reduce the stress of this by giving her safe 'perches' up high where she can see what's going on but feel that she can't be reached.  Cat trees are the usual solution, but high window sills and shelves are also popular with cats, which might be where she has been up there so much.

Over time if your step dad continues to be around, she will become used to his presence, voice and smell, and stress related to the change in routine will decrease as well.